# How to enable on-page editing blue borders for blocks in other languages

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have a multilingual site in EpiServer 7.

I have a block.

This block has some culture specific properties.

The block is only on-page editable in the language that it was created on.

Why aren't the borders showing up in the other languages and how to enable them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a ContentArea or a local block (i.e. a strongly typed property of the block type)?

Either way it should work if you use the [CultureSpecific(true)] attribute on the Content Area or block property.

Comment: Adding `[CultureSpecific]` to a local block will cause a run-time exception.